# TextView многоточие если текст не умещается в TextView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.
Имеется TextView, которая будет зажата с двух сторон другими элементами.
Кол-во символов в textView зависит от ширины экрана/разрешения.
Т.е заранее задать максимальное кол-во символов в textView невозможно.
Нужно реализовать такой механизм:
Допустим для данного экрана макс кол-во символов в textView 76.
А текст который нужно разместить в textView имеет длину 100+ символов, соответственно мы в textView задаем текст из 73 символов и добавляем 3 точки в конце.
Думаю это как то банально решается встроенными средствами TextView, но вот как?????

Comment: Вам нужен ellipsize, кажется

Comment: а именно android:ellipsize="end"  =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Ваш текст"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Максимальное количество линий 1. `ellipsize` вы указываете `end`, текст будет отрубаться с конца строки. И далее вы прописываете `singleLine` и включаете его указав `true`, `silngeLine` устаревший, но он работает и еще полезен.